# Do badges get deleted if question is deleted?

Tags: discussion

If a question is deleted, that awarded me some badge, do I lose that medal?

For example, if I got a famous question on a question, but it was closed/deleted, does my badge get revoked?

Comment: I assume this question was prompted by a recent deletion. I don't *believe* they're revoked, but I suspect you're in a great position to check and answer this for yourself.

Comment: Not exactly. I was just curious.

Comment: And no, does not apply to the battletoads question I had.  That one had too many downvotes.

Comment: Although I do know that my rep came back after the question was deleted.

Comment: I'm gonna guess and say no. There's actually a badge for deleting your own question if it has more than three downvotes!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[No, you do not.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17854/134175) If you get any badge and then the cause of getting that badge is reversed, you keep the badge but you don't get another the next time you would have gotten the same badge.

For example, if you get a Nice Question badge and then the question drops below 10 votes or is deleted, you keep the badge, but the next time a question of yours gets to 10 votes it doesn't grant you another badge.

The real algorithm is that every time another post of yours hits the criteria for a badge, if you have more posts meeting that criteria than corresponding badges, you get another badge.

Comment: So in theory, if I have 2 posts at 9 votes, then one gets upvoted (I get a badge) and downvoted, and then the other gets upvoted, I will not get another badge even though 2 separate posts hit 10?

Comment: Exactly. The post I linked to explains it in more detail.

Comment: @InvaderSkoodge - But if the first post gets another upvote (back up to 10), you'll end up with 2 badges, if I'm interpreting this correctly

Comment: Yes, if both posts are at +10 at the same time, you will have 2 of the badges