# If a question is deleted, what happens to any reputation linked to it?

Tags: discussion, questions, reputation, deleted-questions

Let's say someone creates a question, and after 2 days, puts a 50 reputation bounty. The question gets upvoted 20 times, and 3 answers get put on it. Answer A gets upvoted 5 times and gets accepted (along with the 50 reputation). Answer B gets upvoted 3 times, and answer C gets downvoted 2 times (but not deleted/removed). Then, for some odd reason, the creator deletes his own question. What happens to the reputation earned by both the asker and the answerers?

I already know what happens to badges (thanks to [this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5526/do-badges-get-deleted-if-question-is-deleted)), but what happens to reputation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/158321) FAQ on MetaSE you will read that:

> - Reputation changes from bounties and votes (both up and down) on deleted posts (including answers to a deleted question) are nullified. (Exception: Reputation earned for posts with a score of three or higher, and where the post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days, is retained).
> - Reputation lost as a penalty for having a post deleted by flagging is not returned.

Answer (score 2):

I do believe that we block unilateral owner deletion for questions with upvoted answers (with the exception of mods).

In case the question becomes off-topic and deleted everybody will keep their reputation iirc so long as the question is six months old and your post has enough score.

Comment: So if for some odd reasdon, a moderator deletes a question with upvoted answers, the reputation changes will not revert (even for the asker)?

Comment: @ShadowZ. I have deleted a few downvoted questions before (unanswered) and there was no rep. change for me.

Comment: You stayed with rep lost?

Comment: I've regained rep from deleting downvoted questions. However, the rep reappeared after some time had passed after deleting it.